# Dynamic object creation in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am a total swift noob. I am trying to build dynamic objects. In my example I am trying to create instances of a PAGE class from my BOOK class. I guess I am not sure how to dynamically create them/name them or reference them for use later. I understand I cannot create dynamic names... I am guessing I put them into tan array? Any help or input appreciated.

```
//page class
class pageview : UIView {

    var page: UIView!

    init () {

        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bookwidth, height: bookheight))

        page = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: bookposx, y: bookposy, width: bookwidth, height: bookheight))
        page.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        book.addSubview(page)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}


//book class
class bookview : UIView {

    var cover: UIView!
    var backcover: UIView!
    var page: UIImageView!

    init (numberofpages: Int) {

        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bookwidth, height: bookheight))

        //pages
        for i in 0 ..< numberofpages {

            //PROBLEM HERE
            let page (i) = pageview()
            self.addSubview(page (i))

        }


    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}


//add book
let book = bookview(numberofpages: 3)
container.addSubview(book)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I undestand your question correctly. But check this out:

```
class bookview : UIView {
var cover: UIView!
var backcover: UIView!
var pages: [pageview] = []

init (numberofpages: Int) {
    super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))

    //pages
    for _ in 0 ..< numberofpages {
        let page = pageview()
        pages.append(page)
        self.addSubview(page)
    }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
} }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer